# UIButton highlight animation

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton

Is there any way to highlight button for 0.1 sec more after touching? I'm using setImage for stateHighlighted, but my button blinks if I press it very fast.

And one more thing. In iOS 7 at the phone screen (with numbers) used very interesting animation. Highlighted button is slowly fading and then returns to normal state. Maybe somebody know, how to realise it?

Answer (score 3):

You can animate ALPHA property of your UIButton

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    yourButton.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        yourButton.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:nil];
}];
```

This will fade your button out over a 0.25 second period. Set the alpha to 1.0 to fade it back in again.

Comment: I was trying to user this property, but didnt get required result. Will try again now.

Comment: It works, but it animates normal state of button, not highlighted. And I still dont know when should i set alpha to 1.0 again.

Comment: You need to use completion block for setting back the alpha to 1.0.

Comment: Hmm. Now it works good, but there another problem. I cant press my button again if animation is still going. But anyway, thank you for advice, I will think about solution.

Comment: Found it! I added UIImage over my button and animated it with your method.

Comment: Great. I was about to mention that. Glad it worked for you :).